# Adding three static fields

Tags: c#, static, field

In the below code if we use constant fields, Result will be OK! but when we use static field, the result isn't expected.

**Why and How?**

```
class Program
{
    private static int x = y + 100;
    private static int y = z - 10;
    private static int z = 300;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}",x,y,z); // 100/-10/300  why and how?
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your output is wrong.  It returns a positive 300 for z.

Comment: thanks Juharr, it was corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Member variables are initialized in the order they appear in the file. At the time x is initialized, y and z are both 0.

Comment: and constant members?

Comment: @programmer1, constants are replaced by their values in the compiled code, so the order doesn't matter

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/12/03/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-static-readonly.aspx

Answer (score 2):

z hasn't been initalized yet. Change the order you're initializing your variables in.

```
class Program
{
    private static int z = 300;
    private static int y = z - 10;    
    private static int x = y + 100;       

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}",x,y,z);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer

```
390/290/300
```

Comment: All Right, that is only an example code to show problem and it's not real code, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Constant expressions are fully evaluated at compile time (See section 7.19 of the C# specification).

Since constant expressions are allowed to reference `const` members of a class, the values of the `const` members are computed at compile time. This is why you get the "correct" result using `const` fields.

Compare this with the `static` fields which are evaluated at runtime in the order they're declared.